# PowerShell 7.2 and Invoke-WebRequest Issue

Tags: powershell, get, screen-scraping, invoke-webrequest

I am remodeling my house and need to compare material prices from different websites in order to get the best deal. I am trying to use PowerShell 7.2 and the Invoke-WebRequest command to scrape the item cost. For the life of me, I can't get the following to work and need some help.

```
$Url = 'https://www.lowes.com/pd/CertainTeed-Common-5-8-in-x-4-1-2-ft-x-12-ft-Actual-0-625-in-x-4-ft-x-12-ft-Drywall-Panel/1003189188'

$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -UserAgent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0'
```

When I execute this in PowerShell 7.2, I get the following error...

```
Invoke-WebRequest:
Access Denied
Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;lowes&#46;com&#47;pd&#47;CertainTeed&#45;Common&#45;5&#45;8&#45;in&#45;x&#45;4&#45;1&#45;2&#45;ft&#45;x&#45;12&#45;ft&#45;Actual&#45;0&#45;625&#45;in&#45;x&#45;4&#45;ft&#45;x&#45;12&#45;ft&#45;Drywall&#45;Panel&#47;1003189188" on this server.
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;25784017&#46;1639352283&#46;bd0c2fa
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are being redirected from 'https://' to 'http://' ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar issue.
Any IWR I run gets the following response: -

`Invoke-WebRequest: The requested address is not valid in its context.`

Running powershell 7.2.7
N.B when running the exact same request in powershell 5.1, it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).